# How to call method of another class in android

Tags: android

I have two different class(class A and Class B). i want to use the method of Class A in Class B. i normally used object for class A and called method in class B. but unfortunately i am getting Force close error. Is that any thing different to call a method of another class in android. I referred many articles in stackoverflow. but i cant understand properly. pls help me to find out the solution.

Comment: Is class `A` extends an `Activity` ? If yes, then this is wrong and you shouldnt instantiate an activity. Leave this task to the framework. If that class doesnt extends `Activtiy`,  add the content of your classes in your post

Comment: When you get a force close, there is usually a dump of an exception in logcat. Look at that and it should give you an idea of where the problem is. (In my experience, 90% of the time, it's a NullPointerException from an uninitialized variable.)

Comment: @ccheneson The class which i used as A extends an Activity. whats is the solution to call a method of another class in case if both the class extends Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of Android, class which extends Activity will maintain its life cycle methods. if method which is defined in different class other current running activity may be killed or in pause state. so it is suggested that if method which is reusable in application should in different class for example **(AppManager singleton class)** rather than being in single activity class

Answer (score 4):

You should not create object like this, you should use context to call object like as below

```
           ((Class A) contextObject).function();
```

it runs perfectly on my system,

Answer (score 2):

earlier class A and class B both are extending Activity and now only A extends Activity and B extends A and now B can call functions of A 
this works for me:-

```
public class A extends Activity
{ 
  functionOfA(){}
}

public class B extends A
{
  //calling function of class A
  functionOfA();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

u have to create constructor of class A
& in class B make an obj to class A
initialize it with

```
ClassA obj=new classA();
obj.method_A();
```

hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, you shouldnt instantiate activities. 
If your method uses some method that are called from a `Context` object, you can create a new class ( `Class NewClass`) that accepts a context parameter and implements your methods in it.

So this way, you can call your class from any activity:

```
NewClass nc = new NewClass(this);
```

Look up for some example of how to use a database in Android. It uses the same way.