# How to set a double method equal to a value in a static method?

Tags: java, android, methods, static, double

I have a method called `getX1()` which gets data from a different class:

```
    public double getX1(){
    double x1 = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("s_xd2");

    return x1;
}
```

and I want to set this equal to a value in a static method.

```
    public static double[] xWerte() {
    double x1 = getX1();

    return new double[] {x1,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0};
}
```

But it won't let me... How does it work?

**It says:** Non-static method 'getX1()' cannot be referenced from a static context

Answer (score 1):

> It says: Non-static method 'getX1()' cannot be referenced from a static context

Right - that's got *nothing* to do with creating an array, or anything like that.

The problem is that `getX1()` is an *instance* method - it needs to operate on an instance of the declaring class. Your `xWerte` method is a *static* method, so it doesn't naturally have an instance to operate on.

Options:

- Make `xWerte` an instance method too
- Give `xWerte` an instance of the class to work with (e.g. passing it in as a parameter)
- Make `getX1` a static method (probably tricky, given the `getIntent` call)

Comment: Option 1: Can't to that because it has to be static Option 2: Don't know how it works (coding amateur) Option 3: Maybe to difficult :(

Comment: Is there an other option to get the data from a different class which works with static?

Comment: @Feuer1978: Now would be a good time to *stop* trying to do a complex application, and learn the basics of Java. Your first comment shows that you're not really familiar with the language, which means that you'll have a very hard time trying to solve this problem... so you should take the time to learn the language properly, at which point you'll hopefully have a much better chance of fixing it. Fundamentally, if you need to get instance-based information (as it looks like you do), then *something* is going to need to know the relevant instance.

Comment: @Feuer: That's good for specific issues, but you really should learn the basics of the language more systematically. Otherwise you'll be permanently in over your head.

Comment: @Feuer: I've given you more than a hint. I've given you three options and explained exactly what the problem is. If that's not enough, that's a clear sign you should put some more time into the fundamentals.

Comment: well...problem solved...made everything instance and [extended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854171/how-to-call-method-of-another-class-in-android) my class with a different class to get that method.

Answer (score 0):

A static method can only call static methods. this is because static methods doesn't belong to any specific instance of the class but non static methods are bound to each instance of the class. So when you are trying to call getX1() from a static method, it doesn't know from which instance of the class to call the method from. To solve the problem, either just put the equation into the static method or make getX1() static.

Comment: A static method can call instance methods - it's just that you need to provide an instance to call them on.