# is there way to access main context without don't sent context? on android

Tags: android

I made a custom class called "CustomClass".

Basically, we send main context follow in

In MainActivity,

```
CustomClass cClass = new CustomClass(this);
```

In CustomClass,

```
public CustomClass(Context context){
  this.context = context;
}
```

But, I don't want to send a context in MainActivity.

Just call constructor in MainActivity,

```
CustomClass cClass = new CustomClass();
```

And then CustomClass got Context of MainActivity.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Oh!,
I don't want these way. such as write

```
android:name ="com.example.CustomClass"
```

in Manifest.xml

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5854201/5156075

Answer (score -1):

Make your application like this [BaseApplication](https://github.com/leo7723/ManageActivity/blob/master/BaseApplication.java)
But you have to Make a get method.

Then add MainActivity in it. And use it in your CustomClass.

Or you can just use Application Context instead of MainActivity.

Depends on you using it for what.

Answer (score -1):

Declare static Context in your Application class. Like this

```
public class MyApp extends Application(){
   public static Context context;
   @Override
   public void onCreate(){
      super.onCreate();
      context = getApplicationContext();
   }
}
```

Then use it anywhere in your app.
For example:

```
public CustomClass(){
  this.context = MyApp.context;
  //Or directly use MyApp.context when you need
}
```